# Android Firestore Toggle Button reverting back to false state with button selectors

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, android-selector, android-togglebutton

I'm trying to make my first project on my own. it's basically a stack overflow replica.

I am currently at the part where I'm trying to get the "checked answer" mark to show up green whenever someone views a question if an answer has been selected.

Here is my problem:

When I click the checkmark, it has a tendency to revert back to the black checkmark instead of the green checkmark. I am using a toggle button with selectors and a Firebase Firestore on my Android app. This is what my discoveries have lead me to however this could also entirely be wrong. Some direction and guidance would be appreciated.

I currently have my app set up to read the Firestore field for "checked". If true, show green checkmark, if false, show black. This is all in a recycler view. Please see code below.

**AnswerAdapter**

```
@Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AnswerAdapter.AnswerHolder answerHolder, final int position, @NonNull final Answer model) {

        final String answerFirebaseIdString = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).get("answerFirebaseId").toString();
        final CollectionReference answerCollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Answers");
        final DocumentReference answerDocRef = answerCollectionRef.document(answerFirebaseIdString);

        answerDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.get("checked") == "true") {                      answerHolder.answerCheckMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_check_green_24dp);
                }

            }
        });


         answerHolder.answerCheckMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // update answer isChecked to true

                final String answerFirebaseIdString = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).get("answerFirebaseId").toString();
                final CollectionReference answerCollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Answers");
                final DocumentReference answerDocRef = answerCollectionRef.document(answerFirebaseIdString);

                answerDocRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        boolean answerCheckedFalse = false;
                        String answerCheckedBoolean = documentSnapshot.get("checked").toString();
                        if (answerCheckedBoolean == "true") {
                            answerDocRef.update("checked", answerCheckedFalse).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "answerCheckmark has been set to false.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {


                            answerDocRef.update("checked", answerCheckedTrue).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "answerCheckmark has been set to true.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

**check_mark_selectors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp" android:state_checked="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_green_24dp" android:state_checked="true"></item>
</selector>
```

**answer_item.xml**

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/answerCheckMarkId"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:background="@drawable/check_mark_selectors"

    />
```

I am trying to do something similar with the upvote downvote buttons as well but I am having a similar but different problem.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Finally here is a snippet of my app. Top 1/3 is the question. Bottom 2/3 is the list of answers.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I go into the activity, the checkmark is not green for answers where checked: true. they are black. I am trying to get them to be green when the screen is loaded.